# React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies,but the following modules are linked manually: react-native-google-signin

Tags: react-native

While building my project using react-native run-android command, I'm getting this error:
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-google-signin: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - react-native-google-signin (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-google-signin")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink " and it will be included in your app automatically.

I have upgraded my app

```
From:
"react": "16.4.1",
"react-native": "0.56.0",
"react-native-google-signin": "^0.12.0",
To:
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "^0.60.5",
"react-native-google-signin": "^2.0.0",
```

Google Signin feature is working fine in old app but after upgrading it's throwing error.
I ran this command 'react-native unlink react-native-google-signin' but error msg doesn't go away though the build runs successfully .

**My android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
     ext {
          buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
          minSdkVersion = 22
          compileSdkVersion = 28
          targetSdkVersion = 28
          supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
          googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "+" 
          googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
         }
repositories {
google()
jcenter()
}
dependencies {
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0")
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
mavenLocal()
maven {
// All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
}
maven {
// Android JSC is installed from npm
url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
}
google()
jcenter()
}
}
subprojects {
afterEvaluate {project ->
if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}
}
}
}
```

**My android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**

The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
These basically call react-native bundle with the correct arguments during the Android build
cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle" line.
project.ext.react = [
// the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
// the entry file for bundle generation
entryFile: "index.android.js",
// whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
bundleInDebug: false,
// whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
bundleInRelease: true,
// whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
// See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
// The configuration property can be in the following formats
// 'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
// 'bundleIn${buildType}'
// bundleInFreeDebug: true,
// bundleInPaidRelease: true,
// bundleInBeta: true,
// whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
// for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
devDisabledInStaging: true,
// The configuration property can be in the following formats
// 'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
// 'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
// the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
root: "../../",
// where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
// where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
// where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
// require('./image.png')), in debug mode
resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
// where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
// require('./image.png')), in release mode
resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
// by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
// that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
// date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
// indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
// for example, you might want to remove it from here.
inputExcludes: ["android/", "ios/"],
// override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
// supply additional arguments to the packager
extraPackagerArgs: []
]
*/
project.ext.react = [
entryFile: "index.js",
enableHermes: false, // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**

Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
An APK that only works on ARM devices
An APK that only works on x86 devices
The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
*/
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
/**

Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
/
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
/*
The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
allowing to use e.g. Date.toLocaleString and String.localeCompare that
give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
/
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
/*
Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here. If it is not set
on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
*/
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);
android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.biofreshapp"
minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"

}
splits {
    abi {
    reset()
    enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
    universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
    include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"


    }
}
signingConfigs {
    debug {
    storeFile file('debug.keystore')
    storePassword 'android'
    keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
    keyPassword 'android'
    }  
    release {
    if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
        storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
        storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}
release {
// Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
// see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.outputs.each { output ->
// For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
// https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
if (abi != null) { // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
output.versionCodeOverride =
versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
}
}
}
packagingOptions {
pickFirst '/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
pickFirst '/x86/libc++_shared.so'
pickFirst '/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
pickFirst '/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
pickFirst '/x86/libjsc.so'
pickFirst '/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
//implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
//implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))
if (enableHermes) {
  def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
  debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
  releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
  implementation jscFlavor
}
// implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin")){         
//     exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" 
// }
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
}
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'DemoApp'
include ':app'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android /native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
```

gradle.properties file contains:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
package com.biofreshapp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/build.gradle`, I can still see the dependency is being linked. Should remove the line below.

```
implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))
```